# Do I need to specify the branches to list commits between two revisions in JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want to get the list of commits between two revisions (hashes) in a repository using JGit.

I don't know if the commits (start commit hash, end commit hash) are in one branch or different ones.

I know how to walk through the Tree starting from a commit in JGit.

My question: Do I have to look up the commit hashes in all the branches of the repository or can I use just `Respository::resolve()` like this:

```
Repository repository = git.getRepository();
walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve(commitHash));
```

and be sure that I will find both of commit start and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches, and also other refs (e.g. tags) are just *pointers* to commit ids. Hence you can safely use commit ids to list the revisions between two commits.

To complete your example:

```
ObjectId startCommit = walk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( startCommitId ) );
RevCommit endCommit walk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( startCommitId ) );
// configure and use walk
```

Comment: So I can safely use walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve(commitHash)) ?